# Django - ForeignKey - how to use it correctly?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have following DB model:

```
class Table1( models.Model ):       
    sctg = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Sctg")
    emailAddress = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Email Address", default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str( self.sctg )


class Table2( models.Model ):

    sctg = models.ForeignKey( Table1 )
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Street")
    zipCode = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Zip Code")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str( self.sctg )
```

and I would like to execute select query.
This is what I did:

```
sctg = Table1.objects.get( sctg = self.sctg )
data = Table2.objects.get( sctg = sctg  )
```

and it works but now I am executing 2 queries. Is there a chance to do this in only one ? in raw SQL I'd do a JOIN query but no idea how to do this in Django models.

Comment: No, `self.sctg` is already a lazy reference to a `Table1` object, and if you really want to do it very fast, you can use `sctg_id`.

Comment: But if I understand it, your `self.sctg` is here a string?

Comment: @Willem, yes, self.sctg is a string

Comment: @das-g , yeah, sorry, I mean  Foreign key

Comment: so, can you provide an example of the correct usage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two *consecutive* underscores to look "through" a `ForeignKey` reference. So your query is equivalent to:

```
Table2.objects.get(sctg__sctg=self.sctg)
```

The non-boldface part thus looks through the `ForeignKey`, whereas the boldface part corresponds to the `CharField` column.

Note that

1. it is possible that there is no such `Table2` element, or multiple. In both cases this will result in an error. In case you want to retrieve *all* (possibly empty), you can use `.filter(..)` over `.get(..)`;
2. here `self.sctg` should be a `str`ing (or something string-like) since the `sctg` of `Table1` is a `CharField`.

The above will result in some sort of query like:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 AS t2
INNER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t2.sctg = t1.id
WHERE t1.sctg = 'mysctg'
```

where `'mysctg'` is the value stored in you `self.sctg`.